# Unexplainable memory error after running code

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory, scikit-learn

So I'm testing a few codes, and every time I run it I get memory error. I've even used the following line in anaconda prompt, I really don't know what to do at this point. Also the computer is 64 bit on 32 and task manager says it is only using 35% of the available memory.

What I used at anaconda prompt:

`jupyter notebook --notebook-dir='D:/'  --NotbookApp.iopub_Data_Rate_Limit=1.6e10`

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest


df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\4-Final\\Final After.csv',low_memory=True)

iso_forest = IsolationForest(behaviour='new',n_estimators=300, contamination='auto',random_state=42)

X=(df['Power_kW'].values.reshape(-1,1))



iso_forest = iso_forest.fit(X)
isof_outliers = iforest.predict(X)
isoF_outliers_values = df[iforest.predict(X) == -1]
isoF_outliers_values
```

The error:

```
<ipython-input-1-daa0d1f74aa1> in <module>
     18 
     19 
---> 20 iso_forest = iso_forest.fit(X)
     21 isof_outliers = iforest.predict(X)
     22 isoF_outliers_values = df[iforest.predict(X) == -1]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\iforest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    285         # else, define offset_ wrt contamination parameter, so that the
    286         # threshold_ attribute is implicitly 0 and is not needed anymore:
--> 287         self.offset_ = np.percentile(self.score_samples(X),
    288                                      100. * self._contamination)
    289 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\iforest.py in score_samples(self, X)
    381 
    382         n_samples_leaf = np.zeros((n_samples, self.n_estimators), order="f")
--> 383         depths = np.zeros((n_samples, self.n_estimators), order="f")
    384 
    385         if self._max_features == X.shape[1]:

MemoryError:
```

Comment: What is `(n_samples, self.n_estimators)`? What are the specific numbers?

Comment: How big is the CSV?

Comment: @a_guest n_samples is 300, and n_estimators is unspecified.

Comment: @AMC about 1.62GB

Comment: "Unexplainable memory error": It's perfectly explainable, your computer ran out of memory while trying to fit the model. Have you searched the error and tried using less data or some regularization to reduce the memory footprint?

Comment: @G.Anderson I did search the error, and all the answers were that the computer is running out of memory, but task manager points out that it is using 5.2GB memory out of 16 GB. I did try to use a smaller CSV file, I also chose to apply Isolation forrest on only 1 column out of 19, I still end up getting memory error.

Comment: What version of `sklearn` are you using? There were memory issues with IsolationForest reported [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12469) and apparently improved [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12543)

Comment: @calestini Thank you very much, I'll take a look at it now.

Comment: @calestini So my version is 20.3, and using "pip install -U scikit-learn" and I think I just updated it to version 22.1

Comment: @AliYoussef If it makes sense, try to run with smaller datasets, sample data, just to test the upper limits of memory it can handle.